# Using $watch method in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I'm following the book "Pro AngularJS" by Adam Freeman. But I'm stuck at listing 15-10. The code he provided doesn't work at all.

The demo code is below. It's supposed to work in the following manner: when we click on the button to modify the prices, this list must update automatically. Would you please let me know how to fix his code? I've googled a lot but ....

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">
<head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-theme.css"/>
    <script>
        angular.module("exampleApp", [])
                .controller('defaultCtrl', function ($scope) {
                    $scope.products = [
                        {name: "Apples", category: "Fruit", price: 1.20, expiry: 10},
                        {name: "Bananas", category: "Fruit", price: 2.42, expiry: 7},
                        {name: "Pears", category: "Fruit", price: 2.02, expiry: 6}
                    ];
                    $scope.incrementPrices = function(){
                        for(var i=0; i< $scope.products.length; i++){
                            $scope.products[i].price += 1;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .directive("unorderedList", function () {
                    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                        var data = scope[attrs["unorderedList"]];
                        var propertyExpression = attrs["listProperty"];

                        if (angular.isArray(data)) {
                            var listElem = angular.element("<ul>");
                            element.append(listElem);
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                var itemElement = angular.element('<li>');
                                listElem.append(itemElement);
                                var watcherFn = function (watchScope) {
                                    return watchScope.$eval(propertyExpression, data[i]);
                                }
                                scope.$watch(watcherFn, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                                    itemElement.text(newValue);
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })

    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3>Products</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="incrementPrices()">Change prices</button>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div unordered-list="products" list-property="price | currency"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors appearing on console? Your watcherFN function seems to expect the scope as an input param, but in your $watch definition this is not provided to it - I'd expect an error along the lines of "cannot call $eval of undefined".

Comment: No there is no error, its a feature of the book, see my answer which comes from 15-11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just continue reading, in next capture 15-11 they will tell the previous code doesn't work.

```
If you load the directives.html file into the browser, the directive won’t keep the li elements up-to-date. If you look
at the HTML elements in the DOM, you will see that the li elements don’t contain any content. This is a problem that
is so common that I want to demonstrate how to fix it even though it results from a JavaScript, rather than AngularJS,
feature.
```

Here code from 15-11 which adds function closure
http://jsbin.com/ducihibahi/1/edit?html,output